# Multi select picklist values appear in much smaller font

Tags: picklist, multi-select, font

I'm having some strange behavior with a multi-select picklist.

When I first try to inline edit the multi select picklist, the values are in a very small font.  However, if I click out and click back in, the normal font size is restored.

Additionally, when on the edit page, the values are small again.

Very strange indeed as this is on the standard Case page...any ideas?

Before:[image: Before]
After:[image: AFter]

Comment: did u try in different browser ? can u post a screenshot of what you see ?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I added Before and After shots.

Comment: Try different browser? Clear cache? What language/locale are you using?

Comment: Just clear cache it will be restored back to the default size.